# Escape characters in jQuery variables not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, escaping

I'm having issues with escaping characters (namely period) found in variables when using selectors in jQuery.  I was going to type this all out, but it was just easier taking a screenshot of my console window in Chrome.

[image: Chrome Console Screenshot]

It looks like the variables and the clear text versions match up.  I expect `$('#'+escName)` to return the div, just like `$('#jeffrey\\.lamb')` returns a div.  It does not.  Why?

Comment: Looks like you're putting too many backslashes in `escName`. It should just be `"jeffrey\\.lamb"` You only need one backslash in the string before the `.` in order for jQuery/Sizzle to recognize it as an escape.

Comment: That's the first thing I tried.  I've had times (I think in perl) where you had to escape the escapes when used in variables, so I gave that a shot, too.

Comment: It’s working for me. Please [edit] your question and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Pointy, you're right.  When defining the variable, I had to double escape.  This caused the variable to be singly escaped.  jQuery then only needed the single backslash to use the variable correctly.  Thank you.  I'll accept if you add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to think in terms of the individual parsers that will be examining your string values. The very first one, of course, is the JavaScript parser itself. Backslash characters have a meaning in the string grammar, so if you want a single backslash in a string it needs to be doubled.

After the string is parsed from the source code into an internal string value, the next thing that'll pay attention to its contents (in this case) is the CSS selector evaluator (either Sizzle or the native `querySelector` code; not sure which in the case of strings with escapes like this). That code only needs one backslash to quote the `.` in order that it not be interpreted as introducing a class name match.

Thus, `escName = "jeffrey\\.lamb";` is all you need in this case.