# JQuery Dynamic Selector and special character

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to select the option of a select with a dynamic selector. 
The id of the select is something like this : id="role_toto.test" .

What i'm doing is escaping the dot like this :

```
login= '#role_' + login.replace(/[!"#$%&'()*+,.\/:;<=>?@[\\\]^`{|}~]/g, "\\\\$&");
```

And then i try to select the option and make its attribute selected like this :

```
$(login + ' option[value="'+role+'"]').prop('selected', true);
```

(where role is a variable that i initialized before) but it doesn't work :( . I tried to select the option without the variable like this :

```
$("#role_toto\\.test" + ' option[value="'+role+'"]').prop('selected', true);
```

And it worked but when i do the same thing with a variable it doesn't... 
Can you guys help me ?

Comment: Try to print the _login_ variable...

Comment: When i print the login variable i get exactly what i'm supposed to get : #role_toto\\.test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found the answer to my question thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37844324/escape-characters-in-jquery-variables-not-working)

Basically i just needed one backslash when stocking my string in my variable... 
Hope it'll help other people :)